# Rails RestClient POST request failing with "400 Bad Request"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest-client

Looking at the docs there aren't any good examples of how to make a POST request. I need to make a POST request with a `auth_token` parameter and get a response back:

```
response = RestClient::Request.execute(method: :post,
                        url: 'http://api.example.com/starthere',
                        payload: '{"auth_token" : "my_token"}',
                        headers: {"Content-Type" => "text/plain"}
                       )
```

400 bad request error:

```
RestClient::BadRequest: 400 Bad Request
    from /Users/me/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rest-client-1.8.0/lib/restclient/abstract_response.rb:74:in `return!'
    from /Users/me/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rest-client-1.8.0/lib/restclient/request.rb:495:in `process_result'
    from /Users/me/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rest-client-1.8.0/lib/me/request.rb:421:in `block in transmit'
```

Any good examples how to make a POST request using RestClient?

**EDIT:**

This is how I make the request in the model:

```
  def start
    response = RestClient::Request.execute(method: :post,
                        url: 'http://api.example.com/starthere',
                        payload: '{"auth_token" : "my_token"}',
                        headers: {"Content-Type" => "text/plain"}
                       )
    puts response

  end
```

Comment: Are you sure that your request is `text/plain` request?

Comment: @Pavan curl works so I guess it is right? 'curl "http://api.example.com/starthere" -d "auth_token=my_token"'

Comment: How are you handling the request at the controller? Can you post the related code?

Comment: @Pavan I'm simply printing it to console to see the response as of now

Comment: Try changing `{"Content-Type" => "text/plain"}` to `{"Content-Type" => "text/html"}`

Comment: Also try this instead `RestClient.post 'http://api.example.com/starthere', :auth_token => 'my_token'`

Comment: Any information on this question? Did the answers solved the problem anyway? I am facing the same problem here and would like to know if this worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a hash like this:

```
def start
   url= 'http://api.example.com/starthere'
   params = {auth_token: 'my_token'}.to_json
   response = RestClient.post url, params
   puts response
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to replicate the curl request:

```
response = RestClient::Request.execute(method: :post, url: 'http://api.example.com/starthere',  payload: {"auth_token" => "my_token"})
```

Both Curl and RestClient defaults to the same content type (application/x-www-form-urlencoded) when posting data the this format.

Comment: still getting "RestClient::BadRequest: 400 Bad Request"

Comment: @Tom so I tested with your data got the exact same request with my RestClient snippet as with you curl example. Are you sure that you passed the payload as a hash and not a string?

Answer (score 0):

In case you land here having the same Issue, Just know that this is a common error that happens when your environment variables are not **"set"**.
I put this in quotes because you might have set it but not available in the current terminal session!
You can check if the ENV KEY is available with:

`printenv <yourenvkey>`

if you get nothing then it means you need to re-add it or just put it in your `bash` files

FYI: Putting my ENV variables in my `~/.bash_profile` fixed it